# Im trying to make crawler, how can i get some tags and to get access to internal tags?

Tags: php, html, xml, function, web-crawler

First at all sorry because is difficult to explain what i want to do.

Im making a crawler with php and using the function getElementsByTag() to get some tags i want, for example i want to get some img from the website but are not classifieds by class so i can not filter. The code is the next:

```
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="www.xxx.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Athletic de Bilbao" border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-2UBftyhYArw/T0v9vguvZuI/AAAAAAAAA9s/vLQ8GSo6v5A/s1600/athletic.png" title="Athletic de Bilbao" /></a></div>
<img border="0" src="www.xxx.com/TOl2NhAAFBI/AAAAAAAAAJk/KxHrumDQ48M/s1600/down.gif" /> <b style="color: red;">Bajas</b> <br />
<ul>
```

I'm thinking the one chance I got is to take tag div (separator) and then access with any function to the image tag inside but i dont know if is possible to do with any function?

Comment: Please tag the question with the language you are using. `function` and `crawler` but themselves are completely useless. If you don't do so, not many people will see your question and you won't get any answers.

Comment: sorry, im working php, but i could work to another language if i could finish my crawler

Comment: Can you try Symfony2's DomCrawler component?
http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dom_crawler.html

Answer (score 1):

You can write that as an *Xpath expression*, e.g. to get the list of all such images:

```
//div[@class="separator"]/img
```

You can run xpath expressions in PHP with [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/DOMXPath).

Like with [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/domdocument.getelementsbytagname), [`DOMXPath::query()`](http://php.net/domxpath.query) returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/domnodelist), too.